# Moving from multiple relationships for a single hasManyThrough in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I currently have 3 classes `Elements`, `PageElements` and `Page`. The Models are below:

Pages.php

```
class Pages extends Model
{

    public function pageElement() {
        return $this->hasMany(PageElements::class, 'page_id');
    }
}
```

PageElements.php

```
class PageElements extends Model
{
    public function element() {
        return $this->hasOne(Elements::class, 'id', 'element_id');
    }
}
```

Elements.php

```
class Elements extends Model
{
    //
}
```

All the data I need is from `Elements`, I can throw the `PageElements` data away, how can I convert this to use a `hasManyThrough` relationship?

I would like to directly access the `Elements` via `$page->elements`, currently I have to do `$page->elements->element`.

Am I right in thinking this should be a `hasManyThrough` relationship?

My current attempt is below

```
public function elements() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Elements::class, PageElements::class, 'element_id', 'id', 'id', 'page_id');
}
```

Though is always returns an empty dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I did indeed have the keys mixed up as Jonas mentioned, but just not in that order. My relationship was pairing based off of the wrong id's. The following is correct

```
public function elements() {
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Elements::class, PageElements::class, 'page_id', 'id', 'id', 'element_id');
}
```